# How to make prefabs UI work on any canvas scaller?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

I want to make my UI prefab working on all size of canvas reference resolution scaler because I already make one which is not prefab UI its work to all reference resolution but when I make it prefab and instantiate it it's fit only specific resolution.

like this, I have reference resolution 2560x1440 which normally all UI will be set on that resolution and working fine on 720p or 1080p screen but make it prefab, it's working only on the 2960x1440 screen.

[image: on the 2560x1440]

[image: on the 1920x1080]

[image: on the 1280x720]

here the script for instantiating that object

````cs
public static MM_PilihAyat instance;
    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public List<_PlayerInventory> playerInventories;

    public GameObject pilihAyatPrefab;
    public Transform contentHolderPilihAyat;

    public GameObject bacaPanel;
    public Transform bacaContent;

    private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerInventories.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(pilihAyatPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            go.transform.SetParent(contentHolderPilihAyat.transform);
            MM_PilihAyatItem.instance.inventory = playerInventories[i];
        }
    }

    public void BackToBaca()
    {
        MM_PilihAyatItem.instance.BackToBaca();
        MM_BacaPanel.instance.inventory = null;
    }
```
````

Comment: Did you mean to pass `false` as the second argument to `SetParent`?

Comment: @DMGregory no, my script worked fine, the main issue is the prefab UI only fit on a specific resolution but if not prefab the UI fits on any resolution of the canvas scaler

Comment: @DMGregory oh sorry I'm misunderstanding here yeah like that, so I have to set it false on `worldpositionstays`. Thanks.

Comment: Did that solve your problem? If so, write it up as an Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve this by adding `bool worldpositionstays` when `setParent` which is in my case when instantiating the UI prefab will set on current Canvas scaler resolution

```cs
private void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < playerInventories.Count; i++)
        {
            GameObject go = Instantiate(pilihAyatPrefab, transform.position, transform.rotation);
            go.transform.SetParent(contentHolderPilihAyat.transform,false);
            MM_PilihAyatItem.instance.inventory = playerInventories[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget to click the checkmark to mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem.